ShareGate Migration Error with Specific Service Account
I'm encountering an issue during a ShareGate migration where an unexpected error occurs only when using a specific service account. The error message is as follows:
"An unexpected error occurred: Object reference not set to an instance of an object on server. The object is associated with property CurrentUser."
This error does not occur with other service accounts. Can anyone provide insights on why this might be happening and how to resolve it?
That service should be able to use for migrations
